# Strategy during beta phase

Tags: discussion, beta

Since this beta is out, the community has some development but the Area51 says it has to improve further.

Are there for a member like me any operationalizable actions to improve on that besides answering new questions?

Comment: Publicizing the site is the hardest part, usually it's done by sharing good questions to draw audiance

Comment: ^ +1  I do it by sharing the good question in respective reddit sites :)

Comment: What about cooperating with a popular tech culture site and giving them content as DevOps SE team?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with the *Field of Dreams* concept: "Built it and they will come."

Publicizing the site is important, for visits/day, new users, and new questions, as well as, hopefully, good answers to questions. Publicizing on its own will only help so much, however. As the new prospects make their first visit they need to see quality, and engaging, content. Lacking that, they'll visit once, and disappear. Finding the right content they're likely to explore further and hopefully find a question they either feel qualified to answer, or that expresses a problem they've had and find a useful answer included. Finding a site of value to them increases the likelihood that they will, in turn, share the site with others they know. Every marketing professional knows that the best publicity is also free: word of mouth.

Focus on keeping the quality of the content high, and the site healthy, and the odds of the site surviving are great. It may not *graduate* from beta, but it can still become a permanent site in the Stack Exchange Network.

See the Meta Stack Exchange post [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/351780) for some reassurances.